# como puedo recorrer una colección y añadir un item al final

Tags: laravel, collection

como agrego un nuevo item a una Collection de datos obtenida mediante una consulta sql con laravel.

tengo esta consulta

```
$comprados = DB::table('compra_cursos')
        ->select('materias.id_materia', 'materias.nombre_materia')
        ->join('cursos', 'cursos.id_curso', '=', 'compra_cursos.id_curso_fk')
        ->join('materias', 'cursos.id_materia_fk', '=', 'materias.id_materia')
        ->where('compra_cursos.pago_autorizado', '=', '1')
        ->where('compra_cursos.id_patrocinado_fk', '=', Auth::id())
        ->groupBy('materias.id_materia')->get();
```

la cual me devuelve la siguiente informacion

```
    Illuminate\Support\Collection {#641 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#646 ▼
      +"id_materia": 4
      +"nombre_materia": "El Mundo De La Informatica"
    }
    1 => {#636 ▼
      +"id_materia": 7
      +"nombre_materia": "Como Administrar Bien Una Empresa"
    }
  ]
}
```

lo que estoy tratando de hacer es añadirle 3 nuevos items de tal manera que quede asi

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#641 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#646 ▼
      +"id_materia": 4
      +"nombre_materia": "El Mundo De La Informatica"
      +"comprados": 1
      +"activo": 0
      +"ganado": "0"
      +"tpatro": 0
    }
    1 => {#636 ▼
      +"id_materia": 7
      +"nombre_materia": "Como Administrar Bien Una Empresa"
      +"comprados": 1
      +"activo": 0
      +"ganado": "0"
      +"tpatro": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

Los últimos 3 valores (activo, ganado y tpatro) los saco de otras consultas sql. pero aquí el problema es que se guardan y repiten únicamente lo de la ultima es decir puro 0.
yo lo que busco es que los ultimos 3 valores sean dinamicos por cada iteracion y que quede de la siguiente manera (ejemplo)

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#641 ▼
      #items: array:2 [▼
        0 => {#646 ▼
          +"id_materia": 4
          +"nombre_materia": "El Mundo De La Informatica"
          +"comprados": 1
          +"activo": 5
          +"ganado": "1200"
          +"tpatro": 3
        }
        1 => {#636 ▼
          +"id_materia": 7
          +"nombre_materia": "Como Administrar Bien Una Empresa"
          +"comprados": 1
          +"activo": 0
          +"ganado": "0"
          +"tpatro": 0
        }
      ]
    }
```

les dejo el codigo de mi iteracion y como ocupo la funcion map para poder agregar los items

```
foreach ($comprados as $dataa) {
            $activo = CompraCursos::Diagrama(Auth::id(), $dataa->id_materia)->groupBy('id_patrocinado_fk')->get();

            $ganado = Ganancias::Diagri($dataa->id_materia, $mes_actual, $ano_actual)->get()->last()->monto;

            $totalpatro = CompraCursos::TotalPatrocinados(Auth::id(), $dataa->id_materia)->count();

            if ($ganado == null) {
                $ganado = '0';
            }

            $cactivos = CompraCursos::TotalPatrocinadorActivos(Auth::id(), $dataa->id_materia, $mes_actual, $ano_actual)->count();


                $comprados->map(function ($comprados) use ($ganado, $cactivos,$totalpatro) {
                $comprados->comprados = 0;
                $comprados->activo=$cactivos;
                $comprados->ganado=$ganado;
                $comprados->tpatro=$totalpatro;
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creo que los que estas queriendo hacer debería resolverse asignando al elemento actual del que estas iterando. Tu elemento actual es $dataa por lo que no haria falta el map. Saludos

```
$dataa->comprados = 0;
$dataa->activo = $cactivos;
$dataa->ganado = $ganado;
$dataa->tpatro = $totalpatro;
```

Answer (score 1):

Veo tres respuestas, y ninguna es correcta de acuerdo con las convenciones de Laravel.

La mejor solución sin tener que recrear la colección es usar el método put(), el cual agrega **UN ELEMENTO** a la colección, pudiendo asignarle su llave respectiva.

En ese orden de ideas, se asignan los valores de esta manera, dentro del foreach:

```
foreach ($comprados as $dataa) {
    // obtenemos los valores

    $dataa->put('comprados', 0);
    $dataa->put('activo', $cactivos);
    $dataa->put('ganado', $ganado);
    $dataa->put('tpatro', $totalpatro);
}
```

---

Como referencia les dejo el código del método put, y el del método offsetSet():

```
/**
 * Put an item in the collection by key.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function put($key, $value)
{
    $this->offsetSet($key, $value);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Set the item at a given offset.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $key
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return void
 */
public function offsetSet($key, $value)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        $this->items[] = $value;
    } else {
        $this->items[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Es `$dataa` una instancia de `Collection` o entendí mal la pregunta.  ?

Comment: @Dev.Joel revisa el código del OP, y sí, en este caso es indirectamente una instancia de Collection.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar esa función map, lo que haría sería un simple for.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($comprados);$i++){  
      $comprados[$i]->activo=$cactivos;
      $comprados[$i]->ganado=$ganado;
      $comprados[$i]->tpatro=$totalpatro;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenemos a nuestro alcance un método llamado [`put`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-put) el cual nos va a permitir:

- Recibir una clave como string y la propiedad asociada
- O bien puedes solo pasar las propiedades que traen almacenadas las consultas
- Entonces tu acomodo debería ser: *clave* y separado por coma la propiedad que le dará valores a dicha clave
- Agregar ese nuevo vector a uno existente es decir a una *collection* quedando de esta forma:

Código:

```
$comprados->put("activo", $activo, "ganado", $ganado, "totalpatro", $totalpatro);
```

O así:

```
    $comprados->put($activo, $ganado, $totalpatro);
```

Así deberás ajustar para pasarle el resto de propiedades que guardan tus consultas